# Regex to match a line in a multi-lined string in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have the following code:

```perl
use Capture::Tiny qw(capture);
my $cmd = $SOME_CMD;
my ($stdout, $stderr, $exit_status) = capture { system($cmd); };
unless ($exit_status && $stdout =~ /^Repository:\s+(.*)/) {
    my $name = $1;
}
```

It run the `$cmd` and tries to parse the output. The output looks like:

```
Information for package perl-base:

Repository: @System
Name: perl-base
Version: 5.10.0-64.81.13.1
```

For some reason `$name` is empty probably because it could not group due to multi-lined string. I also tried `/^Repository:\s+(.*)/s` and `/^Repository:\s+(.*)$/` but it didn't work as well.

I want the `$name` to have `@System`. How can I do it?

Comment: You do realize that you can execute code like this without using the Capture::Tiny module? Just use `qx()` or the backticks to capture standard output. Only if you want to capture the other things from the command (exit statues and standard error) should you use this.

Comment: To have your question answered correctly, you should show how you check what `$name` contains.

Answer (score 4):

I believe you want the multiline `m` flag:

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $s = 'Information for package perl-base:

Repository: @System
Name: perl-base
Version: 5.10.0-64.81.13.1';

$s =~ /^Repository:\s+(.*)/m;
print $1; # => @System
```

You can make your regex more accurate with `$` to anchor the end of line and  `+` instead of `\s+`: `/^Repository: +(.*)$/m`.

Comment: Because the input string is multiline, so the anchor `^` is treated as beginning of string rather than beginning of line without the `m` flag.

Comment: Right, the anchor makes that statement correct. But also the variable is not scoped properly. We do not see how he uses the variable, but my guess is no strict, and using the variable outside the block.

Comment: I assume they're printing it in the block, but yeah, that's a good point as well. Ideally they'd show where they're printing it so there's no ambiguity.

Comment: @TLP, Re "*Why would he need the multiline modifier when the match is on the same line?*", because the OP wants `^` to match start-of-line, and the `/m` is required for that. Without `/m`, it only matches start of string.

Comment: @ikegami Yes, we figured it out. Actually, this is a rare case of 3 answers which all may have part of the total solution.

Answer (score 3):

`$name` is empty because it is declared inside a block, which means it is out of scope outside that block. You would know this if you had used `use strict`, which does not allow you to access undeclared variables.

What you need to do is to declare the variable outside the block:

```
my $name;   # declared outside block
unless ($exit_status && $stdout =~ /^Repository:\s+(.*)/m) {
    $name = $1;
}
print "Name is: $name\n";   # accessible outside the block
```

Also, you need to remove the beginning of line anchor `^`, or add the `/m` modifier.

Comment: Wouldn't a better solution be to put the print inside the block? That way, you wouldn't be trying to print undef.

Comment: @ikegami A print might be better inside, but I do not know the OP's logic, the print statement is just a simple example. It demonstrates that to use the value outside the block you need to declare it outside, which is the basis of my answer.

Answer (score 3):

First, the logic of that `unless` statement is broken, as it short-circuts on success:

```
unless ($exit_status && $stdout =~ /^Repository:\s+(.*)/) { ... }
```

is just a syntactic "convenience" for

```
if (not ($exit_status && $stdout =~ /^Repository:\s+(.*)/) ) { ... }
```

So if the command ran successfully and `$exit_status` is falsey (`0` for success) then the `&&`-ed condition is false right there, and so [it short-circuits](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Logical-And) since it is already decided.<sup>†</sup> Thus the regex never runs and `$1` stays `undef`.

But it gets worse: if `$exit_status` were a positive number *and* the regex matches (quite possible), then the `&&`-ed condition is true and with `not` the whole `if` is false so you don't get its block to run! While there was valid output from the command (since regex matched).

So I'd suggest to disentangle those double-negatives, for something like

```
if ( $exit_status==0  and  $stdout =~ /.../m ) { ... }  # but see text
```

Then there must be an `elsif ($exit_status)` to interrogate further. But a command may return an exit code as it pleases, and some return non-zero merely to communicate specifics even when they ran successfully!  So better break that up, to get to see everything, like

```
if ($exit_status)      { ... }  # interrogate
if ($stdout =~ /.../m) { ... }  # may have still ran fine even with exit>0
```

The moral here, if I may emphasize, is about dangers of convoluted code, combined logical negatives, meaningful evaluations inside composite conditions, and all that.

---

Next, as mentioned, the regex attempts to match a pattern in a multiline string while it uses the anchor `^` -- which anchors the pattern to the beginning of the *whole string*, not to a line within, as clearly intended; so it would not match the shown text.

With the modifier `/m` added the behavior of the anchor `^` is changed so to match the beginning of lines within a string.

---

<sup>†</sup>  If this gets one's head spinning consider the equivalent

```
if ( (not $exit_status)  or  (not $stdout =~ /^Repository:\s+(.*)/) ) { ...
```

With falsey `$exit_status` the first `(not $exit_status)` is true so the whole `if` is true right there and the second expression need not be evaluated and so it isn't (in Perl)

Try it with a one-liner

```
perl -wE'if ( 0 and do { say "hi" } ) { say "bye" }'
```

This doesn't print anything; no `hi` nor `bye`.  With `0` the whole condition is certainly false so the `do` block isn't evaluated, and the `if`'s block isn't either.

If we change `and` to `or` though (or `0` to `1`), then the first condition (`0`) doesn't decide yet and the second condition is evaluated, so `hi` is printed. That condition is true (printing statements normally return 1) and so `bye` prints, too.